# No dll file in OpenCV 4.0.0

Tags: java, opencv

I have been trying to use OpenCV with Java without success. I am currently running Linux. I downloaded the OpenCV library from Github, but when I try to run any program, it gives me an error on the line: `System.load(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);`

The error is "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Expecting an absolute path of the library: opencv_java400"

I have been told I need to provide a path to a .dll file; however, the current version of OpenCV appears not to contain any .dll files.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Why do you have 4.0.0? The latest release is 3.4.1

Comment: if you are running linux... then it is not dll :) that is for windows.. it should be something like .so or .a

Answer (score 0):

The message of the Exception is everything you need. You are supposed to provide an absolute path to the file.

Normally you would put the native libraries as resource in your java package (*.jar). Before loading you must extract the file to a temporary directory of the executing system and then invoke the `System.load(..)`.

As already mentioned a dll typically names a dynamic runtime library on windows os.